# Wordpress Plugin with shortcodes causes The White Screen Of Death

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I wrote a plugin, which is working as intended. It adds a shortcode listener and outputs some HTML. The problem is when I re-login to `wp-admin/`, I only see the white screen of death. If I remove my plugin, Wordpress works just fine.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Widgets
Plugin URI: http://dshatz.com
Description: A plugin for generating some website widgets
Version: 1.0
Author: Me
Author URI: http://dshatz.com
*/?>

<?php
function checkout_button_create(){
    $ec = @$_GET['ec'];
    $userId = @$_GET['id'];

    $c = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pwd", "db");
    $stmt = $c->prepare("...");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $userId, $ec);
    $stmt->execute();
    $payment_id = $c->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $c->prepare("...");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $payment_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $price);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

$html = <<<EOD
<h1>$name</h1>
<form id="purchase_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="..." />
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="..." />
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR" />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="$price" />
<input name="custom" type="hidden" value="$payment_id"></input>
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="EN_US" />
<input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="paymentaction" type="hidden" value="sale" />
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="/licenses/purchased/" />
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="WPPlugin_SP" />
<input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="/" />
<input class="paypalbuttonimage" style="border: none;" alt="Make your payments with PayPal. It is free, secure, effective." name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
<img style="border: none; display: none;" src="http://i2.wp.com/www.paypal.com/EN_US/i/scr/pixel.gif?resize=1%2C1&ssl=1" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
EOD;
return $html;
}

function register_form_create(){
    $email = @$_GET['email'];
    if(!isset($email)) $email="";
    $ec = @$_GET['ec'];

    $html = <<<EOD
        <style>
          input{
              float: right;
          }
          form div{
              padding-bottom: 10px;
          }
          .error_indicator{
              color: red;
          }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateEmail(email) {
                var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email);
            }
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("form.register_form").submit(function(e){
                    var fieldsOk = true;
                    var mailOk = false;
                    var mail = jQuery("input[type='email']", jQuery(this)); 
                    mailOk = validateEmail(jQuery(mail).val());

                    jQuery("input", jQuery(this)).each(function(index){
                        if(jQuery(this).val().length == 0) {
                            fieldsOk = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    if(fieldsOk) jQuery(".fill_in_pls").css("display", "none");
                    else {
                        jQuery(".fill_in_pls").css("display", "inline");
                        jQuery(".invalid_email").css("display", "none");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(!mailOk){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        jQuery(".invalid_email", jQuery(this)).css("display", "inline");
                        return false;
                    }
                    jQuery(".invalid_email", jQuery(this)).css("display: none;");
                    return ;  
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form class="register_form" method="POST" action="/license/register.php" style="width: 50%;">
            <div>
                <label for="email_input">Email</label><input id="email_input" type="email" name="email" value="$email"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="fname_input">First name</label><input id="fname_input" type="text" name="fname"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lname_input">Last name</label><input id="lname_input" type="text" name="lname"/>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ec" value="$ec"/>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Checkout"/>
            </div>
              <div class="error_indicator invalid_email" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email</div>
              <div class="error_indicator fill_in_pls" style="display: none;">Please fill in all fields</div>
        </form>
EOD;
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('register', 'register_form_create');
add_shortcode('checkout', 'checkout_button_create');
?>
```

The code is running just perfect when I insert a shortcode on a page. What can cause this awful white screen?

Comment: do you have access to the error logs?

Comment: Which one? `php_errorlog` has nothing in it.

Comment: Your second query is executed after closing the connection, are you aware of that?

Comment: @RST No, as far as I understand I close the statement(`$stmt`). But the connection here is `$c`.

Comment: Sorry, read it the wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this may be it works.

Just replace

> var mail = jQuery("input[type='email']", jQuery(this));

TO

> var mail = jQuery("input[type=\'email\']", jQuery(this));

I have added backslash.

**Full plugin Code :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Widgets
 * Plugin URI: http://danielpataki.com
 * Description: This plugin adds some Facebook Open Graph tags to our single posts.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Daniel Pataki
 * Author URI: http://danielpataki.com
 * License: GPL2
 */
function checkout_button_create(){
    $ec = @$_GET['ec'];
    $userId = @$_GET['id'];

    $c = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "pwd", "db");
    $stmt = $c->prepare("...");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $userId, $ec);
    $stmt->execute();
    $payment_id = $c->insert_id;
    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = $c->prepare("...");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $payment_id);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name, $price);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();

$html = '<h1>$name</h1>
<form id="purchase_form" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_xclick" />
<input name="business" type="hidden" value="..." />
<input name="item_name" type="hidden" value="..." />
<input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="EUR" />
<input name="amount" type="hidden" value="$price" />
<input name="custom" type="hidden" value="$payment_id"></input>
<input name="lc" type="hidden" value="EN_US" />
<input name="no_note" type="hidden" value="" />
<input name="paymentaction" type="hidden" value="sale" />
<input name="return" type="hidden" value="/licenses/purchased/" />
<input name="bn" type="hidden" value="WPPlugin_SP" />
<input name="cancel_return" type="hidden" value="/" />
<input class="paypalbuttonimage" style="border: none;" alt="Make your payments with PayPal. It is free, secure, effective." name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
<img style="border: none; display: none;" src="http://i2.wp.com/www.paypal.com/EN_US/i/scr/pixel.gif?resize=1%2C1&ssl=1" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>';
return $html;
}

function register_form_create(){
    $email = @$_GET['email'];
    if(!isset($email)) $email="";
    $ec = @$_GET['ec'];

    $html = '<style>
          input{
              float: right;
          }
          form div{
              padding-bottom: 10px;
          }
          .error_indicator{
              color: red;
          }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function validateEmail(email) {
                var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
                return re.test(email);
            }
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery("form.register_form").submit(function(e){
                    var fieldsOk = true;
                    var mailOk = false;
                    var mail = jQuery("input[type=\'email\']", jQuery(this)); 
                    mailOk = validateEmail(jQuery(mail).val());

                    jQuery("input", jQuery(this)).each(function(index){
                        if(jQuery(this).val().length == 0) {
                            fieldsOk = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    });
                    if(fieldsOk) jQuery(".fill_in_pls").css("display", "none");
                    else {
                        jQuery(".fill_in_pls").css("display", "inline");
                        jQuery(".invalid_email").css("display", "none");
                        e.preventDefault();
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(!mailOk){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        jQuery(".invalid_email", jQuery(this)).css("display", "inline");
                        return false;
                    }
                    jQuery(".invalid_email", jQuery(this)).css("display: none;");
                    return ;  
                });
            });
        </script>
        <form class="register_form" method="POST" action="/license/register.php" style="width: 50%;">
            <div>
                <label for="email_input">Email</label><input id="email_input" type="email" name="email" value="$email"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="fname_input">First name</label><input id="fname_input" type="text" name="fname"/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="lname_input">Last name</label><input id="lname_input" type="text" name="lname"/>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="ec" value="$ec"/>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Checkout"/>
            </div>
              <div class="error_indicator invalid_email" style="display: none;">Please enter a valid email</div>
              <div class="error_indicator fill_in_pls" style="display: none;">Please fill in all fields</div>
        </form>';
    return $html;
}

add_shortcode('register', 'register_form_create');
add_shortcode('checkout', 'checkout_button_create');
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still white screen. Is there any chance single quotas may be disliked by WordPress?

Comment: @DanielShatz i hav updated my answer.I have added your fully plugin code.and it is working in localhost. thx

Comment: Tested again. Looks like PHP Heredoc syntax is not fully supported in WordPress plugins. Thank you very much. Saved me some time. Too strange there is no info about this on Google.